# user input and acceptance inside a function

Tags: c#

My function accepts user input and then do somework when user clicks ok.

private void cannyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            canny();
        }

```
private void canny()
        {

// get user input
// if user clicks ok 
          if (ok button is clicked)
              {
                  messagebox.show(" you clicked ok")
                // 
               //do dome work
               //
               }


         }
```

But I can't see any messagebox. What I am missing.

```
 private void ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// should I add here some thing
        }
```

what i am missing.
regards,

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: A little more detail on your current setup would be helpful. Also remember to format code.

Comment: What do those ???????????????? behind `Form1.Control.Add(Ok)` stand for? Are my OS's language packs broken, or is my browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is to get the result from a dialog box. If that is the case you want to do the following:

```
private void ShowDialogAndDoSomethingBasedOnTheResult()
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
        "Dialog text",
        "Caption to go in title bar",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Do work
    }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0x49kd7z.aspx for more examples.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you do:

```
private void ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok;
}
```

Which closes the dialog, it will only stay running as long as its DialogResult property is None.  It isn't strictly necessary, you can also use the designer.  Change the button's DialogResult property, now you don't need to write the code.  That is however not often appropriate, you usually want to check if the user provided all the information you require.  Ymmv.